# laravel jquery ajax not redirecting although I see the new page in the console

Tags: php, laravel

I want to do this in laravel: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/redirects

I have a simple button, a named route, and  I want the route to redirect to another page.

Although I see the new page in the network console of Chrome, the page itself is not actually redirecting.

(*I don't want to use the window.location.href in the javascript function as I want the route to do the job.*)

**layout.blade.php**

```
    $("#myRedirectButton").click(function(){

        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });

        $.ajax({
            method: 'post',
            dataType: 'text',
            url: 'redirect-testing-link',
            success: function (data)
            {

            }
        });

    });
```

**routes/web.php**

```
Route::post('/redirect-testing-link', function () {
    return redirect()->route('gidis');
});


Route::get('/gosterge_paneli', function () {
    return view('gosterge_paneli');
})->name('gidis');
```

Comment: This wouldn't work anyway right? You post data, don't do anything with it and then render a view without your data available.

Comment: Why you don't simply use a `href` attribute ?

Comment: @Core972 because I want to do the example as explained in the Laravel documentation

Comment: Just asking why you would need such a big solution for a seemingly very simple problem. The answer is that you can't do it the way you want and need to use either an `<a>` or `window.location`. You simply can't redirect to a new view from the server after an AJAX request.

Comment: @Loek ok you can write this comment as an answer I will choose it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do a serverside redirect after an AJAX request, so what you ask is very hard.

The simplest ways to solve it are by using either the `window.location` you wanted to avoid, or skip the whole AJAX call and use an `<a>` element.